# Dynamic Rating Plugin to Add Anywhere

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, rating, plugin-gd-star-rating

I need to add ratings to a page for a few different fields (ex: color, quality, etc.) - not just per post or comment. I'm generating the page using a template, so I have access to the php file that generates the html.

Is there any pre-existing rating plugin where I can add the rating feature anywhere on the page? (For example, by saying [rate id=5 field=color])

I've looked at [GD Star](http://www.gdstarrating.com/downloads/plugin/), but I don't think it works outside of pages and posts. If this is possible with GD Star, I'd love a link to how to do it - I've looked through their documentation and have come up empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you think using the plugin and then just referencing the plugins functions from your theme, making sure to check that the plugin is active, would work?

Comment: I ended up writing my own functions after seeing code from the NextGen Gallery Voting plugin.

Comment: @Grok - I did something similar to that :) - I was concerned it would take too long since I'm not familiar with wordpress.

Comment: Sweet! I'll post it as an answer then. Maybe it will help people down the road. Oh wait! You answered your own question! :P

Comment: Please post the code if you can. it will be much appreciated as it might help me with my problem. pls see: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/33480/thumb-rating-for-wordpress-top-user Cheers!

Comment: @echez, I didn't end up using GD. We used a gallery component called Next Gen Gallery, and found a plugin for it called NextGen Voting. Then we just created custom functions in the template, for example createVote(..,..) where we manually added the votes we wanted into the database using sql code. And then for the display, we just pulled those out of the database using getVote(..,..).

Comment: @stringo0 As a separate answer, please. SE/SO encourages users to share knowledge. It's fully ok to ask and answer your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the plugin and reference it inside of a function within your theme.

Be sure to check to make sure the expected plugin/function actually exist.

Then you can just use it's functionality as you see fit!