# Thumb rating for wordpress - top user

Tags: plugins, php, wp-query, rating, plugin-gd-star-rating

I am currently using gd star rating (thumb rating) to rate posts (articles - no rating on comments). What I really want to do is show a table of the top 5 users and their number of votes based on the total number of thumbs up they receive for all their posts. For instance

| user | No of votes |

If this is not possible with this plugin, is there any other plugin that is capable of such. Or is there a manual way of achieving what I want. I don't mind manual coding with the right nudge

Many thanks guys

Comment: This is definitely possible - someone with gd experience should be able to answer this. You could start by looking at the database tables gd creates, see if any of them have a user field.

Answer (score 1):

there are varaiables in gd rating to sort query.

you can use in URL  like :

```
http://www.gdstarrating.com/?gdsr_sort=rating&gdsr_order=desc

http://www.gdstarrating.com/?gdsr_sort=review&gdsr_order=desc

http://www.gdstarrating.com/category/tutorials/?gdsr_sort=votes&gdsr_order=asc
```

or pass to a query

```
query_posts("gdsr_sort=rating");
query_posts("gdsr_sort=review&sort_order=asc");
query_posts("gdsr_sort=rating&gdsr_multi=3");
query_posts("gdsr_sort=votes&sort_order=asc&gdsr_multi=3");
```

you can find more info here :

http://www.gdstarrating.com/2009/07/03/how-to-reorder-posts/